# AngularJS - memorizing chosen values in form after returing from some special state (view)

Tags: angularjs

I build some form analogously to: 
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/forms.html
It means that I also use `ng-model` as chosen value. These values are retrieved from database - there are multiselect options.

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="firstName" ng-model="myCtrl.firstName"> First name <br/>
    <input type="text" name="lastName"  ng-model="myForm.lastName"> Last name <br/>
</form>

Controller {
    constructor() {
       this.firstName = getFirstNameFromDatabase();
    }

}
```

It is sketch of my code - I wouldn't like to show it here.

It is working ok - values are retrieved from database and displayed as proposition in form.

My issue is following: 
Let's assume that someone type in this form `"abc"`. Then, someone click button next (it direct to another state, user is directed to another view - lets denote it `X`).

User can return from `X` view with back button. I would like to display `"abc"` (so my app should memorize chosen values). 
However, if user type value `"abc"` and return to menu (or another else state (view) - different from `next` button) - in this case value shouldn't be memorized.

Can you give me some clues ?

Comment: So to clarify -- you want to be able to save draft data between different pages of your application? And I take it this isn't a single page application, the server is actually returning a different page when you switch views?

Comment: Yes, but you should note that it is only about one page (after returning from some one special page it should remember chosen (typed) values to form).

Answer (score 0):

Since you're actually switching pages in your application, you're going to have to put their content in some sort of persistent storage. A couple ideas pop into my head.

- Temporary Browser Storage / Cookies
- Server-side storage in a Database or Cache

Either way, you'll need to store the data whenever the user manipules the values. And when they switch pages, choose whether to clear the data or not based on whether it's your special view.

Or another idea is to use an angular function to change the url (rather than a simple anchor). Then in that function you can persist the data before switching to your view. But if they go to a different page, it won't get saved. This only works if they navigate based on your page's links.

Usually this sort of thing is accomplished using a single page which includes both your original view and the next view. You can swap out the content using JS so the user doesn't know the difference. So that's still an option too.